# Labeling a pool of unlabelled samples iteratively

Tags: sampling, labeling, active-learning

**Problem setting**

I'm faced with a problem in which we have a large set of data points (100K), all of which are still unlabelled. These are to be used as input to a binary classifier at a later point in time. Since sampling is very costly, we need to select a small subset of this pool that is most informative/representative for the dataset and hopefully also for classification.

We could probably do a few (say 3) iterations of sampling (say 200 at first, 1000 later, 1000 in a third phase). It is my understanding that *pool-based active learning* is an ideal solutions for such scenarios once we have some labels, but from what I've read, it doesn't tackle the first iteration when *no labels are known*.

So my questions is: how would you select the first 200 samples to label?

**What I've looked at:**

- Full factorial design of experiment: i.e., sample uniformly from all dimensions (alas, this is not possible because the 100+ dimensions prohibit this)
- Picking a random starting point and selecting whichever point is most informative next according to some predefined criterion (entropy/information gain/...)

Then again, it is probably smarter to get those 200 points at once. Does anyone know the name of such a technique which selects *"the best representation we can have of this dataset"* based on a subset **k**?

Comment: Use [Rényi entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy) or something similar. Probably also useful to have a look at how Nyström approximation is used for essentially similar goals, for instance [here](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/mmahoney/pubs/kernel_JMLR.pdf) and [here](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/ROKS2013/files/abstracts/RaghvendraMall.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the optimal way to pick an initial sample according to information criteria such as entropy is a notorious problem called *maximal entropy sampling*. This turns out to be NP-hard, so I will probably select a small uniform sample of the data and then try to apply maximal entropy sampling afterwards.

For approximations, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/how-to-make-representative-sample-set-from-a-large-overall-dataset) seems to give some pointers as well (though their proposes sample size is huge and probably not applicable to my scenario).